# Any online Greek/Hebrew resources we can quote from?

Tags: discussion

For questions involving the original languages, it would be helpful to be able to link to Bible passages in Greek or Hebrew. There are plenty of online Bibles in modern languages, but much fewer, it seems, in the original languages. Is anyone aware of any online resources with up-to-date versions of the Bible in Greek, Hebrew, and Aramaic (or interlinear)?

Comment: I imagine copyright issues come into play here. I have a copy of the UBS4 Greek New Testament, which (I understand) is identical to the NA27 text... but can it be quoted here?

Comment: @Ray, I don't see why not. For Reference - http://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-fairuse.html#howmuch

Comment: See also [What good reference works on biblical studies are available (freely) online?](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/639/423)

Answer (score 6):

Mechon-mamre.org has [the original Hebrew/Aramaic of the Tanakh with verse-by-verse-adjacent JPS translation](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0.htm), and has several versions without translation: [with cantillation signs and vowels](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0.htm), [without cantillation signs but with vowels](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0.htm), [with neither](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/x/x0.htm), and [with neither, using modernized spelling](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/k/k0.htm).

Answer (score 6):

http://studybible.info/ has a fairly comprehensive selection of interlinear and literal translations as well as a few popular translations.

The site works well for copying and pasting the original language words, has no less than 8 greek interlinears to choose from, and also has some study tools such as Strongs, Vines, and Thompson Chain Reference.

Here is a partial list of many translations it includes, many of which (especially the interlinears) are not available on biblegateway:

> ```
> * ABP_Strongs - Apostolic Bible Polyglot English Text with Strong's numbers
> * ABP_GRK - Apostolic Bible Polyglot Greek Text with Strong's numbers
> * Stephanus - 1550 Stephanus Greek New Testament
> * LXX_WH - Septuagint OT and Westcott-Hort Greek NT
> * Tischendorf - Tischendorf Greek New Testament
> * TR - Scrivener's Textus Receptus
> * SBLGNT - SBL Greek New Testament
> * HOT - Hebrew Old Testament
> * IHOT - Interlinear Hebrew Old Testament
> * IGNT - Interlinear Greek New Testament
> * ACVI - A Conservative Version Reverse Interlinear
> * new - a new revision of Webster's translation
> * Vulgate - Latin Vulgate
> * Clementine_Vulgate - Clementine text of the Latin Vulgate Bible
> * WestSaxon990 - West Saxon Gospels, c. 990
> * WestSaxon1175 - West Saxon Gospels, c. 1175
> * Wycliffe - John Wycliffe New Testament
> * Tyndale - William Tyndale's Translation
> * Coverdale - Coverdale's Translation
> * MSTC - Modern Spelling Tyndale-Coverdale
> * Geneva - Geneva Bible
> * Bishops - Bishops Bible
> * DouayRheims - Catholic Douay-Rheims Bible
> * KJV_Strongs - King James Version with Strong's numbers
> * Webster_Strongs - Noah Webster's revision of the KJV with Strong's numbers
> * YLT - Young's Literal Translation
> * ASV_Strongs - American Standard Version with Strong's numbers
> * CLV - Concordant Literal Version
> * ALT - Analytical Literal Translation
> ```

Another site that has good interlinear and greek word study concordances is http://biblos.com/ though they have seperate urls to get directly to the concordances http://concordances.org/ and interlinear translations http://interlinearbible.org/

Comment: Thank you for the compilation!

Answer (score 6):

[BibleGateway](http://www.biblegateway.com) has become almost a de facto standard on Christianity.SE. They also have the following Greek texts:

- 1550 Stephanus New Testament
- 1881 Westcott-Hort New Testament
- 1894 Scrivener New Testament
- SBL Greek New Testament

For Hebrew, there's The Westminster Leningrad Codex. There's also the Vulgate, which might be relevant for some questions.

I don't know how useful these texts are (I'm not a scholar). One reason for wanting to use BibleGateway might be that there's a [ready-made userscript for generating MarkDown](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/449/60) suitable to be used on StackExchange sites. It doesn't work for Hebrew, unfortunately; I'll look at fixing that if people show interest. For Greek, it should work nicely; example output:

> [**ΚΑΤΑ ΙΩΑΝΝΗΝ 3:16-17 (SBLGNT)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203:16-17&version=SBLGNT)
>
> <sup>16</sup>  Οὕτως γὰρ ἠγάπησεν ὁ θεὸς τὸν κόσμον ὥστε τὸν υἱὸν τὸν μονογενῆ ἔδωκεν, ἵνα πᾶς ὁ πιστεύων εἰς αὐτὸν μὴ ἀπόληται ἀλλὰ ἔχῃ ζωὴν αἰώνιον. <sup>17</sup>  οὐ γὰρ ἀπέστειλεν ὁ θεὸς τὸν υἱὸν εἰς τὸν κόσμον ἵνα κρίνῃ τὸν κόσμον, ἀλλ’ ἵνα σωθῇ ὁ κόσμος δι’ αὐτοῦ.

Answer (score 5):

The (fairly new) **Scripture Study App** provided by Calvin Theological Seminary (extending John Dyer's Bible App) is also excellent.

Try, for example [Joshua 5:1](http://study.calvinseminary.edu/?verse=Josh.5.1) in Hebrew (choose the "WLC" text option for one panel), or [John 5:1](http://study.calvinseminary.edu/?verse=John.5.1) for Greek (choose the "SBL" module in one panel).

Keep an English translation (NETi works well) in the other panel. Run the cursor over verses and words to see the highlights in *both* panels. Grammatical information is also available: use the large "plus" (+) icon in the upper right corner.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Be sure to also check out [What good reference works on biblical studies are available (freely) online?](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/639/423)

Answer (score 2):

I personally like the [Online Hebrew Interlinear Bible](http://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/Hebrew_Index.htm).  It shows the King James version off to the side.  The same site has the [Online Greek Interlinear Bible](http://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/Greek_Index.htm).

The downside is that everything downloads in PDF, so it's useful if you do screen captures and upload images.  Not as useful for copy-paste (like BibleGateway is).

Answer (score 2):

I very much appreciate the NET Bible's "Classic" [website](http://classic.net.bible.org/bible.php).  (The updated version resists direct links, which makes it all but worthless for our purposes.)  In addition to Greek and Hebrew texts, the notes within the translation are the most informative of any Bible translation I've ever seen.  I especially appreciate the textual criticism notes for their direct dealing of "troublesome" texts.  In this era, we would do well to pay attention to note just how Greek gets translated into English, but which version of the Greek is used.  The NET Bible's notes also cover other aspects of the text which may be useful in answering (or asking) questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of good sites for interacting with the biblical text. My favorites are listed on [this guide for exegesis](http://libguides.bju.edu/bible) that I wrote in my previous job at a library.

Perhaps we could interface with YouVersion for easy insertion of Bible text from English, Greek, or Hebrew versions?

Answer (score 1):

## The tools I use in 2022

### FYI: Logos.com

First, I have an account (not a subscription) at [logos.com](https://logos.com). I love buying resources from there, though this is not an ad. I do use it.

But, while I do research from Logos, we can't really quote from there in a way that supports links. If I need quotes from paid resources that can't be linked to online, the copy-paste action automatically creates the non-link, standardized citation information for printed materials.

### Free, online, link-supportive materials

#### 1. [biblegateway.com](https://www.biblegateway.com/)

- Free to use
- Supports links to chapter, verse, and translation
- Supports many translations in many languages
- Owned by Zondervan

#### 2. [biblehub.com](https://biblehub.com/)

- Supports parallel translations
- Useful for Strong's numbering
- Has other Bible study tools

#### 3. [biblestudytools.com](https://www.biblestudytools.com/)

- Many translations
- [Has SBLG (Greek)](https://www.biblestudytools.com/sblg/)
- Linkable by chapter

#### 4. [chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/)

- Online [Hebrew Bible](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/63255/jewish/The-Bible-with-Rashi.htm) with English parallel

I have to say that I don't use the Hebrew Bible for answers because it is not my area of expertise.

#### 5. [StudyLight.org](https://www.studylight.org/)

- I enjoy this for [Vine's Dictionary](https://www.studylight.org/dictionaries/eng/ved.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Aleppo codex](https://barhama.com/ajaxzoom/viewer/viewer.php?zoomDir=/pic/AleppoWM/&example=viewer5)

Answer (score 0):

[Sefaria is home to 3,000 years of Jewish texts. We are a non-profit organization offering free access to texts, translations, and commentaries so that everyone can participate in the ongoing process of studying, interpreting, and creating Torah](https://www.sefaria.org/texts)

Answer (score 0):

[Early Jewish Writings is the most complete collection of Jewish documents from antiquity with translations, introductions, and links. The Early Jewish Writings web site is copyright © Peter Kirby. Permission is given to link to any HTML file on the Early Jewish Writings site.](https://www.earlyjewishwritings.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Greek and Roman history 323 - 30 B.C. This site contains detailed lists of events and sources for the history of the Hellenistic world and the Roman republic. It includes links to online translations of many of the sources, as well as new translations of some works which have not previously been easily available in English. To look at what's available, click on one of the links below.](https://www.attalus.org/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Our flagship collection, under development since 1987, covers the history, literature and culture of the Greco-Roman world. We are applying what we have learned from Classics to other subjects within the humanities and beyond. We have studied many problems over the past two decades, but our current research centers on personalization: organizing what you see to meet your needs.](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/)