# Latin Vulgate online search

Tags: discussion

How to search the Latin Vulgate for a word? Is any online website or mobile app or other software ( especially free ) available?

Comment: Install [*Theophilos*](http://www.theophilos.com/download.htm), and then its [*Vulgate*](http://www.theophilos.com/lib01.asp) module.

Comment: Personally, I would want to be able to search Jerome's translation rather than Clementine. Challoner used Jerome's translation in publishing the Douay-Rheims version.

Comment: Why was this migrated? It [does not belong](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3209/2672) on Meta.

Comment: @Keelan While I agree with you, some others think Meta should be used for questions about tools used in the field Biblical Hermeneutics, rather than only about the site itself. (I have long favored a tag for such questions on the Main site.) Your close vote will trigger a decision by the community for this question.

Comment: @Susan that is pushing the boundaries of the community's abilities a little bit, in my opinion.

Comment: @Keelan Haha, you make a good point, but this is the mechanism we’re left with. Could raise it in [chat] if you think it’s worthwhile discussing further.

Comment: stepbible.org is the perfect site for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should meet your requirements:

https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=ponamque+foedus+meum&t=VUL#s=s_primary_0_1

Comment: ofcourse, exactly what i was looking for, thanks a million :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use [VulSearch](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/) (unfortunately currently only for Windows, although since it's open source you could theoretically port it to other OSs). It includes the Douay-Rheims (the English translation *par excellence* of the Vulgate) so you can search both a strict English translation of the Vulgate or the Latin of the Vulgate itself; or even the Septuagint (although only **transliterated** Greek).

[image]

It also comes with a very useful word search function (for searching Latin or English).

[image]

(A feature where you could search for a several-verse-wide range of text with the search parameters would make this tool even more useful in my opinion).

And even a Latin word dictionary.

[image]

And of course it's free.

Highly recommend it. I realize this sound like an advert or something but it genuinely is the simplest solution for those who want the Vulgate, along with the meaning of the Latin, in one app. I use it every other day.